# Recreate App Catalog site in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, app-catalog

We have couple of modern UI apps (.sppkg files), that work fine in various tenancies. For one particular tenancy, these apps are not getting deployed and we see correlation error. And we see this message in admin center to create the app catalog site (image below). Though it exists and we are able to navigate to it and upload apps. And we are able to upload apps from admin center as well.

[image]

And we are not able to navigate to client site assets library in app catalog site.
https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/AppsForUs/ClientSideAssets/AllItems.aspx

As a workaround, can we delete the current app catalog site and recreate it? Is this a safe operation that will not cause any other issues? App catalog does not have any other app as of now. Please let me know the steps as well to recreate. Thanks.

Comment: We tried few things like enabling and disabling CDN (Get-SPOTenantCdnEnabled and related commands). Next day it started working. Do not understand the root cause and fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have created the app catalog with low privilege account.

*Account used to create App Catalog, Must be Tenant administrator.*

- You can remove the app catalog as it is not configured properly created.
- ***ClientSideAssets*** library should be present at app catalog site. app package files get deployed in this library.
- Follow below steps to create app catalog.

1. Sign in to Office 365 with your SharePoint Online admin account.
2. Go to the SharePoint admin center.
3. Select Apps from the Quick Launch bar on the left, and then select App Catalog.
4. Select Create a new app catalog site, and then select OK.
5. On the Create App Catalog Site Collection page, enter the required information, and then select OK.
6. Navigate to the new App Catalog within the SharePoint admin center by selecting  Apps and then clicking App Catalog.

> App catalog will take around 20 to 30 minute to get created.
> So you have to wait for 20 to 30 minute to get it created.

Comment: thanks for looking into it. I added comment a comment to post.